# How to know the traditions to follow for events?

Tags: tradition

How do we know about any important traditions to follow during a marriage or vrata or festival etc.

What are all the items required, how to follow the process, what are good days to do it etc.

Earlier parents used to remember the things but now a days every one became busy and difficult to remember them, and approaches priests in temples for suggestions but is there a way to know them from internet.

Answer (score 2):

The best way for me is to buy a Bengali Panjika. I buy either a [Benimadhav Panjika](https://www.amazon.in/Bengali-Madhav-Panjika-English-2019-2020/dp/B07NQKV35T) or a Madana Gupta one for each Bengali year. 
And, these books will have all the needed info, the kind of you are looking for and of course much much more.

Each such book will have a separate section called *Vrata Prakarana*, which deals with various Vratas celebrated by any Hindu throughout the year.

For e.g. Shivaratri vrata, Mangala Chandi vrata, Satyanarayana vrata, Itupuja vrata, Vipattarini vrata, Lakshmi friday vrata, Shanidev vrata, Janamshtami vrata and many others.

And, for each such vrata the necessary details related will also be given.

For e.g. for Shivaratri vrata they have given a list like:

- Vrata Niyama - This section lists all the necessary rules to be followed.

  - Vrata Upakarana - All the ingredients you need to successfully complete the vrata.
  - Vrata Phala - The fruits one obtains after successfully completing the vrata.
  - Vrata Katha - There is usually a story associated with each vrata which one has to listen (or recite) on the day of fast. This section gives such stories for a particular vrata.

So, the easiest way for you will be to buy a hard copy Panchanga for your own region. It will also have all details of everything needed to conduct a marriage properly as it is done in your region.

Which are the auspicious dates for marriage, Chudakarana, Annaprashana etc are also listed in all such Panjikas (Panchangas).

---

For online resource, you can check Drikpanchang.com. On this site you will get lots info about when is what vrata but the information found in a hard copy is much much more detailed.

For e.g. from [this page](https://www.drikpanchang.com/vrats/hindu-vrat-list.html) you can find the list of various Hindu vratas. And as you click on the vrata you are interested in, you will find list of all the days of the year which are the vrata days.

As an example, [here](https://www.drikpanchang.com/vrats/sankashti-chaturthi-dates.html) are the Sankashti Chaturthi vrata (a vrata dedicated to Lord Ganesha) dates for the whole year.